# kubctl get deployment READY 0/0 meaning

Tags: kubernetes

I see a lot of heavy documentation online related to Kubernetes deployment but still can't find the definition of `0/0`.

```
> $ k get deployment 

NAME                                                            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
async-handler-redis-master                                      1/1     1            1           211d
bbox-inference-4k-pilot-2d-boxes                                0/0     0            0           148d
```

What exactly does it mean to be `0/0`? It's deployed but not ready? Why is it not ready? How do I make this deployment `READY`?

Answer (score 2):

It means replica of your deployment is 0. In other words you don't have any pods under this deployment so 0/0 means 0 out of 0 pod is ready.

You can;

```
kubectl scale deployment <deployment-name> --replicas=1
```